# Where can I find utilities for SSRS Report Portal 2016

Tags: reporting-services, report

I am looking for utilities/code that has been developed to make the SSRS Report Portal 2016 user friendly/simpler for users that have zero technical background — interested in anyone who has developed an ordinary-language interface that can be configured for domain specific (schools, in this case) purposes.

The users need to be able to access the Portal, select a Template from a Library, and configure it to meet their own own needs — without having to understand any of the technical issues, or write any code.  Eg. the Templates will contain auto-populated dropdown menus that allow the user to select the source and type of information that can be placed into a specific section of the report they are building.

Comment: You might want to investigate Power BI for your requirements. For example it allows you to pin pre-generated visualisations as tiles on to a dashboard. Is that what you have in mind? I suggest you try that out and then explicitly list any reasons why this does or doesn't work for you. Remember that information isn't as simple as a 'source and type' - there are many permutations of combining, filtering, grouping information that result an identical looking reports with different numbers, _however each report correctly answers a slightly different question_.

Comment: I did a PoC with PBI — is is several years away from the non-technical user.  I'm seeking a solution that makes use of leading-edge AI.  Your points are correct — but there is no reason why filtering, grouping, etc have to be presented to the user in a technical language.
I have already designed  system that uses ordinary language for schools to undertake complex multi-variate analyses based on highly complex models (not the simplistic analyses of BI systems).
I'm just looking for a parallel approach to the design of reports — if no one has done this yet, I'll do so in the next 12 months.

Comment: My approach is outlined at the links below.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/next-generation-educational-analytics-peter-cuttance?published=t

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/next-generation-educational-analytics-part-1-peter-cuttance?published=t


https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/next-generation-educational-analytics-part-2-proposed-peter-cuttance?published=t

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/next-generation-educational-analytics-part-3-asking-data-cuttance?published=t

Comment: Those are very interesting articles. SSRS is only going to be useful for you as a drill through target. That's really it's strength - canned reports that take parameters that are accessible via URL's. There is a whole SSRS API that you can use but you won't be able to build anything like what you're after in it. You're better off building your custom solution and using it to trigger pre -built SSRS reports. If I understand correctly you are building a system that models schools. SSRS is only useful to you if you add pre canned SSRS reports to your existing model.

Comment: With regards to PBI, I only refer to it as a reference point (I'm by no means an evangelist). In PBI, assuming a model is already built, which parts are too technical for the average user? You can drag and drop build reports, and you can have them on a running on an iPad with zero code. The modelling component is technical but there's no way to avoid that. Building metadata layers that facilitate drag and drop is nothing new. The tricky part is disambiguating the data (is that date the event date or the posted date or the payment date or the enrolment date?)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who uses excel and pivot tables, with a little training, could easily make simple reports with report builder. The interface will let you drag and drop data if you have a tabular or multidimensional model. It works very similar to excel. Mobile report publisher is even easier if the data provided to them is well designed for that intention.

Comment: Why should a user expect to have to be trained to access basic information?